# Cannot create property 'cart' on string '{}lax'

Tags: magento2, cart, customer-data

I have a very annoying problem: randomly our customers get the next javascript error, which hangs the shopping process, it also appears in the cart view.

[image]

Has anyone had this problem? what's happening here??

Thank you very much for your answers!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is due to a feature in Magento called 'section' or 'private data'. It is intricate to debug.

I suggest to check error logs, server error logs but often these are verbose.

I will list the possible solutions from simple to harder..

- you need to find a way to replicate it reliably and then disable the most recent modules first and test again.
- the hardest solution is to use a dev environment of your site and debug. For this solution, you will need some dev skills and I suggest to check whether the function `\Magento\Customer\CustomerData\SectionPool::getSectionDataByNames` throws some errors in your system. To do this, just add log onto this function just for the development environment that is.

Comment: It doesn't always go wrong, it goes wrong sometimes. There is no error message in the log file. With Magento, I'm a novice.  Don't you say tomorrow/Magento/Customer/CustomerData \ SectionPool: : getSectionDataByNames file specific how should operate, don't know if you can tell me.  thank you

Comment: How does Magento know when the Module was installed?  I don't remember what module was installed at the end

Comment: My answer was indicating you that you have to remember the modules you have installed. Magento is not built with this feature in mind. With the feedback you're giving, your only option is to debug. It is not that hard, you just need to install your environment locally

Comment: {"cart":1661997397,"directory-data":1661996503,"bss-fbpixel-atc":1661997388,"messages":1661997397}lax                                                                 
I found the problem because the value of section_data_ids has lax attached to it, but I don't know where that came from